# Storing notifications appropriately, based on the corresponding input channel

Tags: java, spring, email, aop, separation-of-concerns

I have the following problem. In my application, every user could execute actions through a web client, as well as through email. Every action (a method in a controller class) has to implicitly store a notification in an external key-value store (I am using Redis) In addition, if the action was executed via email, the executor has to be notified about the state of the action (success/failure) via email as well. The main problem that I experience is how to engineer the whole structure with maximum separation of concerns. For instance, I do not want the controller methods themselves to do anything about storing the notification/sending a response email.

Initially I wanted to use AOP, and simply decorate my methods with @Action("actionType"), unfortunately I would also need to know who the sender is. As far as I know, I cannot assign values to annotation attributes at runtime, so I had to think of another way.

The second approach would be to use an "Around" intereceptor, to stop the execution of a method, grab the current user (from a session-scoped userService), but again, that would work for the web controller only, because the mail processing class is stateless, and is unaware of a concept such as currentUser (the only way I can grab the sender is through the email paramater that it is supplied with, every time when a new mail comes)

I guess, the simplest approach would be to call a notification service explicitly, from every method that needs notification (in both, the web request controller, and the mail processor), but again, that would lead to the methods knowing a little bit too much.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with the AOP approach, but I'd let the aspects share a [`ThreadLocal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) that holds user information and is initialized by an Aspect that catches the email when it comes in. That way you can implement the entire logic without changing your application code.

Nice question, by the way.